# Validating a Django model field based on another field's value?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app with models accessible by both Django REST Framework and a regular form interface. The form interface has some validation checks before saving changes to the model, but not using any special Django framework, just a simple local change in the view.

I'd like to apply the same validation to forms and REST calls, so I want to move my validation into the model. I can see how to do that for simple cases using the validators field of the Field, but in one case I have a name/type/value model where the acceptable values for 'value' change depending on which type is selected. The validator doesn't get sent any information about the model that the field is in, so it doesn't have access to other fields.

How can I perform this validation, without having essentially the same code in a serializer for DRF and my POST view for the form?

Comment: This [section from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) may be helpful, although it does not deal with the REST part.

Comment: Or [Model.clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) may do it for some cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The validation per-field doesn't get sent any information about other fields, when it is defined like this:

```
def validate_myfield(self, value):
    ...
```

However, if you have a method defined like this:

```
def validate(self, data):
    ...
```

Then you get all the data in a dict, and you can do cross-field validation.

Comment: This answer is in the context of a DRF `ModelSerializer` subclass.  Though an analogous situation exists in the Django model, for `clean_myfield` and `clean` methods.  Are you POSTing via DRF or not...?

Comment: Yes and no. I have a DRF api, but also a view that a form posts to.

Comment: Why not use a ModelSerializer instance in the form's clean? This keeps the validation code in one place.

Comment: It's not a modelform, just a pair of view functions (show form and process post)... I think I am probably making my life harder than necessary though :-) There are definitely options to make the ModelSerializer the only point for validation.

Comment: You don't have to actually post to the API to use the `ModelSerializer`.  You can also just import and instantiate a serializer to use it for the validation.  Although this is somewhat unusual, it's possible and in fact often useful in tests.

Comment: I am getting      validator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'. How can i call the validator function now?

Answer (score 15):

I dug around codebase of drf a little bit. You can get values of all fields using following  approach. Doing so, you can throw serialization error as
`{'my_field':'error message}` instead of `{'non_field_error':'error message'}`.

```
def validate_myfield(self, value):
   data = self.get_initial() # data for all the fields
   #do your validation
```

However, if you wish to do it for ListSerializer, i.e for `serializer = serializer_class(many=True)`, this won't work. You will get list of empty values.
In that scenario, you could write your validations in `def validate` function and to avoid `non_field_errors` in your serialization error, you can raise `ValidationError` with error message as a dictionary instead of string.

```
def validate(self, data):
    # do your validation
    raise serializers.ValidationError({"your_field": "error_message"})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Why are others trying such difficult approach? This must be accepted answer.

Comment: I am getting      validator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'. How can i call the validator function now?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [required](https://github.com/shezadkhan137/required) package for your cross-field validation. It allows you to express your validation rules declaratively in python. You would have something like this with DRF:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    REQUIREMENTS = (
        Requires("end_date", "start_date") +
        Requires("end_date", R("end_date") > R("start_date")) + 
        Requires("end_date", R("end_date") < today.date() + one_year) + 
        Requires("start_date", R("start_date") < today.date() + one_year)
     )

    start_date = serializers.DateField(required=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = serializers.DateField(required=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        self.REQUIREMENTS.validate(data)  # handle validation error
```

You could put the `REQUIREMENTS` on your Model and have both your DRF and Django Form validate your data using it.

[Here](https://shezadkhan.com/required-a-easy-dependency-validator/) is a blog post explaining more